# Issue with getting discord bot to Heroku

Tags: python, windows, heroku, discord, deploying

Every time. I have 2 pythons should I delete the smaller version and try then?

```
ERROR:
    -----> Python app detected  
     !     Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.  
     !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile  
    -----> Installing python-2.7.13  
    -----> Installing pip  
    -----> Noticed cffi. Bootstrapping libffi.  
    -----> Installing requirements with pip
           Ignoring cffi: markers 'sys_platform == "win32"' don't match your environment
           Collecting discord.py[voice]~=0.12.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3682dfc47a0ab41c4e4f075cfcc32bc9/requirements.txt (line 1))
             Downloading discord.py-0.12.0.zip (440kB)
           Collecting youtube_dl (from -r /tmp/build_3682dfc47a0ab41c4e4f075cfcc32bc9/requirements.txt (line 2))
             Downloading youtube_dl-2017.4.26-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB)
           Collecting aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0 (from discord.py[voice]~=0.12.0->-r /tmp/build_3682dfc47a0ab41c4e4f075cfcc32bc9/requirements.txt (line 1))
             Downloading aiohttp-1.0.5.tar.gz (499kB)
               Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
               Traceback (most recent call last):
                 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
                 File "/tmp/pip-build-4Ij98a/aiohttp/setup.py", line 60, in <module>
                   raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+")
               RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+

               ----------------------------------------
           Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4Ij98a/aiohttp/
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
     !     Push failed

Requirements.txt
discord.py[voice] ~= 0.12.0
youtube_dl
pip
cffi==1.6.0; sys_platform == 'win32'
```

Comment: From the [discord.py docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-a-syntaxerror-around-the-word-async-what-should-i-do) the minimum required version of Python for a bot is Python 3.4 (or more specifically 3.4.2) due to the requirements of the AIOhttp module.